# Null-Pointer in recursively search function after return

Tags: java

I have a class that uses an internal binary tree as a data structure. I have a weird problem. I'm recursively looking for a specific node. If the node is found I want the code to return the reference to it. The problem: After return it's always null! But why?

```
private HeapNode getHeapNode(double key) {
    //ELEMENT IS NOT AVAILABLE HERE, NULL-Pointer, ALWAYS
    return getHeapNodeRec(key, rootHeapNode);
}

private HeapNode getHeapNodeRec(double key, HeapNode curr) {
    if (curr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (curr.getKey() == key) {
        //ELEMENT IS AVAILABLE HERE, I can access its data!
        return curr;
    }
    else {
        getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getLeft());
        getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getRight());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `return null` at the end of method ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the return value, when you **discard the return value** in the recursive calls?

Comment: why don't you fire up your java debugger and see

Comment: this should never return null if the key is in the tree because of return curr;?

Comment: Then I would suspect it's not finding the key if you are sure that it will do that.

Comment: @blahfunk It likely is finding the key, but not on the root node, so it's in a recursive call, and the recursive calls discard the return value and return null instead. Oops!!!

Comment: The "Return" only goes up a single level of recursion. When you return return `curr`, that value is just passed to the calling function - usually the next level up of `getHeapNodeRec`, which then discards it and proceeds to return null.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think this is a duplicate of `What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?`

Comment: @Andreas there is no NPE thrown, he's just returning `null` when he shouldn't

Comment: The dup is about how to find the source of a null value (the cause of NPE), so the answers in the dup are very on-point for this question: *Why do I have a null value, and how do I fix it?*

Comment: @phip1611 did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you’re getting `null` is because you’re tossing the node away after you start stepping back out:

```
else {
    getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getLeft());
    getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getRight());
}
return null;
```

You search the left and the right nodes, but then after getting the results of that search, you don’t preserve the result, and just return `null`, propagating `null` all the way back up to the root call.

What you should do is something along the lines of:

```
else {
    HeapNode leftResult = getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getLeft());
    if (leftResult != null) { 
        return leftResult; 
    }

    HeapNode rightResult = getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getRight());
    if (rightResult != null) { 
        return rightResult; 
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm sorry, I sometimes still have problems with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value that you are recursively fetching, like so.

```
private HeapNode getHeapNode(double key) {
    //ELEMENT IS NOT AVAILABLE HERE, NULL-Pointer, ALWAYS
    return getHeapNodeRec(key, rootHeapNode);
}

private HeapNode getHeapNodeRec(double key, HeapNode curr) {
    if (curr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (curr.getKey() == key) {
        //ELEMENT IS AVAILABLE HERE, I can access its data!
        return curr;
    }
    else {
        if (getHeapNodeRec(key, curr.getLeft()) != null) {
            return curr.getLeft();
        }
        if (getHeapNodeRec(key, current.getRight()) != null) {
            return curr.getRight();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```